# Lodash chaining issue

Tags: lodash

I am having trouble getting the value of my chain. I believe it has something to do with the `return`s in my code.

```
      let wrapper = _.chain($scope.meetings)
    .orderBy($scope.meetings, function(o) { return new moment(o.meetingDate); }, ['asc'])
    .filter($scope.meetings, function(o) { return moment(o.meetingDate).isAfter(begin) && moment(o.meetingDate).isBefore(end); })
    .forEach($scope.meetings, function(o) { o.createdBy = $scope.myData[0].fullName;})
    .value();
```

I am getting an empty array as the value

Comment: Remove the `$scope.meetings` from the call to orderBy, filter and forEach. The output of the orderBy will be collection that filter will use etc.

Comment: That is the answer

Answer (score 0):

as @gruff-bunny said, solve was to remove the variable from my orderBy, filter, and forEach. In the end, my function looks like this.

```
        $scope.meetings = _.chain($scope.meetings)
      .orderBy(function(o) { return new moment(o.meetingDate); }, ['asc'])
      .filter(function(o) { return moment(o.meetingDate).isAfter(begin) && moment(o.meetingDate).isBefore(end); })
      .value();
```